# Display Row from Another Related Table from MySQL Using fetch_object()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, relational-database, echo

Trying to echo the author column from a another table. Currently have two tables in database one is called `entries` and the other `comments`. Both have IDs but both have the same column name "author". In the SQL statement you would do `select * from $table1 t1, $table2 t2 where t1.blogID = t2.blogID and t1.blogID = $postID`. I know how to echo from just one table using `fetch_object()`

```
if (!empty($postID)) {
$command = "select * from $table_name where blogID = $postID";
$result = $db->query($command);
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $postID = $data->blogID;
  echo "<TR><TD>".$postID."</TD>";
  echo "<TD>".$data->author."</TD>";
  echo "<TD>".$data->date."</TD>";
  echo "<TD>".$data->entry."</TD></TR>\n";
```

But, then, if I want the `$command` to select on both tables, how would I echo let say `t1.author`? Meaning do I do `$data->t1.author`? Does that make sense? Or what do you guys suggest using the format I've set-up above?

Comment: You need to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: @MarcB thank you for your suggestion but that's not helpful.

Comment: Then perhaps `var_dump($data)` will show you what you need to do, once you've done the joined query.

Comment: @MarcB hmm what does that do to echoing a column from a second table. Basically, I'd like to use `$data->t1.author` pseudo syntax to echo this second column on another table.

Comment: you're asking how to access it from the query results. `$data` is a row of your data. So dump it out and see exactly what's in there. That'll show you how PHP has mapped your `t1.author` field into an array key, and its corresponding value. THAT's what you need to use to echo out the value.

Comment: @MarcB oh ok. I've never tried that. Good pointer. I'll try that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$command="select t1.name as t1name , t2.name as t2name from t1tabla as t1 ,t2table as t2";
$result = $db->query($command);
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {

 echo $data->t1name .'<br>';
 echo $data->t2name.'<br>' 
}
```

Comment: it will work @mythoslife. Maybe you are doing something wrong.This is how it works.Please check your query.print_r($result) to check what is it giving.